# Change lockscreen time and date font?

Tags: lock-screens, fonts

Starting from Android 6.0, Google altered how their lockscreen looks in AOSP, presumably to increase readability:

- Digital clock is smaller
- Digital clock uses a bolder font, presumably Roboto Medium
- Date text is ALL CAPS
- Date text has a noticeable character spacing

A comparison can be seen in the pic below.

[image]

It seems that this is Google's design vision going forward, as Android 7.x only kept or reinforced upon those points, and the recently released [Fuchsia OS preview](https://www.theverge.com/circuitbreaker/2017/5/8/15579846/google-fuchsia-os-magenta-armadillo-first-look-ui) is in the same style.

However, as good as Google's intention might be, I'm not a fan of *all* these points above, and now that I see Google is determined to push it (Fuchsia), I'm determined to revert it back to what it was in Android 5.x. I'm rooted, have a custom recovery, and know how to decompile and recompile APKs, so I should be ready for whatever's needed.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more searching, I finally came across an [XDA-Developers thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g/themes-apps/mod-android-m-lockscreen-clock-gpe-t3123898) explaining how to do it - or rather, how to do the reverse action of what I want to achieve (credits to the original author there). I'll post an excerpt of the core part and reverse the action yet again to make it fit my purpose.

> 1. Install apktool.
> 2. Install your `framework-res.apk` by executing `apktool if /path/to/framework-res.apk`.
> 3. Decompile your `SystemUI.apk` by executing `apktool d /path/to/SystemUI.apk`
> 4. Go to the decompiled `SystemUI` folder and open `res/values/styles.xml`.
> 5. Search for `big_thin` and replace `sans-serif-light` behind `<item name="android:fontFamily">` with `sans-serif-thin`.
> 6. Open `res/values/dimens.xml`.
> 7. Search for `widget_label_font_size` and replace `14.0sp` behind it with `16.0sp`.
> 8. Open `res/layout/keyguard_status_area.xml`.
> 9. In the two lines starting with `TextClock` and `TextView`, remove `android:textAllCaps="true"` and `android:letterSpacing="0.15"`.
> 10. Rebuild `SystemUI` (preserve its signature) by executing `apktool b -c SystemUI`.
> 11. Push the finished `SystemUI.apk` back to where it was using a method of your choice, set correct permissions, then reboot.

The end result is pictured below. Font size might still use some tweaks, but generally favorable result.

[image]

**P.S.1:** For the record, and for ROM makers who are interested: you can also modify the same files prior to building the ROM - find the files above in `*build-folder*/frameworks/base/packages/Keyguard/`.

**P.S.2:** Interestingly, while searching for "reverting the font on 6.0+ back to what it was in 5.x" didn't return anything, searching for "changing the font on 5.x so it looks like 6.0+" (the opposite) did return more favorable results, as there were quite a number of Marshmallow wannabes back then. I guess that's a lesson learned in Google-fu...